# SonarQube not extending timeout

Tags: linux, azure, sonarqube, azure-devops, ubuntu-16.04

I'm getting an error when trying to use SonarQube with TFS Online. Its timing out during processing. I changed the sonar.properties file and restarted the service. But I still get an error saying it timed out because it didn't finish in 300 seconds. I've even tried scaling the server to give it more power. I'm currently under, [D2_V2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/) on Azure.

#### sonar.properties

```
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=900000
```

#### error

```
2017-03-11T20:12:34.4141248Z Waiting on the SonarQube server to finish
processing in order to determine the quality gate status.
2017-03-11T20:12:34.4141248Z  2017-03-11T20:12:34.4141248Z 
2017-03-11T20:17:34.7999965Z
##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The analysis did not complete in the allotted time of 300 seconds. Consider setting
the build variable SonarQubeAnalysisTimeoutInSeconds to a higher
value. ---    System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The
analysis did not complete in the allotted time of 300 seconds.
Consider setting the build variable SonarQubeAnalysisTimeoutInSeconds
to a higher value. 2017-03-11T20:17:34.7999965Z    --- End of inner
exception stack trace --- 2017-03-11T20:17:34.7999965Z    at
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input) 2017-03-11T20:17:34.7999965Z    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke) 2017-03-11T20:17:34.8009662Z    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync) 2017-03-11T20:17:34.8009662Z    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-03-11T20:17:34.8009662Z    at
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-03-11T20:17:34.8009662Z    at
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args) 2017-03-11T20:17:34.8109668Z
##[error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1. 2017-03-11T20:17:34.8109668Z ##[section]Finishing: Complete the
SonarQube analysis
```

Comment: You need to set this `SonarQubeAnalysisTimeoutInSeconds` in a Build Variable in the build definition to up the timeout. Just like the message says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says:

> The analysis did not complete in the allotted time of 300 seconds. Consider setting **the build variable `SonarQubeAnalysisTimeoutInSeconds`** to a higher value

Go to the Variables tab in the build definition, add the above mentioned variable and up the value.

Comment: do you know where I can find a list of sonarqube build variables?

Comment: Looking at the source code, this is the only one. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/releases/m100/Tasks/SonarQubePostTest https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/releases/m100/Tasks/SonarQubePreBuild

Comment: But now that SonarSource has taken up the maintenance of these tasks, that may change. I hate these hidden things, Either put it in the UI or in a documented config file, if you ask me.